# running maco on cell value change

Tags: dynamic, excel, vba

so

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim KeyCells As Range          
   Set KeyCells = Range("d4")
        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then Call fftest                   
   End Sub
```

This code does its job fine, if I change the value in "D4" then the sub `fftest` is called".

But for it to take affect I have to click out side the cell.

Is there any way to get it to notice every key stroke I enter? so for example if i was to enter "123" in to cell D4, the sub would be called after the 1, the 2 and the 3, so run 3 separate times.

I want a list to be dynamic lay updated as people type in to the cell, so they can see the results after each keypress.

Cheers

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell

Comment: Cool cheers for that :) I would accept that as a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see Siddharth Rout answer in comments. I would happly accept the comment as an answer if possible