# Using Worksheet Macro to hide FALSE Row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

[image]

I am trying to hide the Rows that are false.

Currently I have

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Range("B10:B13") = False Then
        Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: Shouldn't it automatically Toggle when the values change from True to False?

Comment: Mostly runtime errors if I try to make edits to the sheet.

Comment: You're not looking for the string "False", you're looking for a `False` condition. If you do look for the string, you'll see the solution in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterating over each cell in the range and testing its value like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("B9:B13")
        If Not c.Value Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Edit: I think another way you can achieve the result you are after is to remove the series from the chart

```
Dim n As Long
With ChartObjects(1).Chart
   For n = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
      With .SeriesCollection(n)
          If .Name = "" Then
              .Delete
          End If
      End With
   Next n
End With
```

Comment: Would I just Add Else C.EntireRow.Hidden = False   Assuming I wanted it be be visible, when I change it to True

Comment: Why do I have to click under the True False to get it to change?

Comment: @MichaelDowney re. adding `else ...` then yes if you need them to reshow them. re. clicking under this is because it is only when you leave the cell, confirming the entry, that the worksheet has changed. You could try [capturing keypress events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell)

Comment: Thanks! Hmm you would not happen to have simpler way to remove the blank from the Legend Key would you? Since that was the reason for making the row hidden initially.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i = 9 to 13
if range("B" & i) = "False" then
    Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
end if
next
```

Comment: `Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True` is allowed as well. And `Rows(i).Hidden = True` and `Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True` too. But I like your answer for +1.

Comment: Wow, those are great. Thank you!