# How to call a function on ENTER key in Excel using vba

Tags: excel, windows-7-x64, excel-2016, vba

Google should provide me with ample examples but none of them seem to work

**What I want:** Everytime the user presses, and then releases, the ENTER key, for my program to do do something (ie. create a MsgBox, or call function Foo). I would prefer this in the form of a MWE

**What I have done:** I have tried *googling it* but none of the examples are functional. They compile, but don't do anything. I have also made sure to save in a macro compatible Excel format.

**What I am using:** I am using Excel 2016, 64 bit with Office 365

**EDIT:** The user is entering this information into the worksheet. I want to intercept the user input and everytime they press ENTER, take the cursor/active cell down two rows, so there is an empty cell below every cell. If the user presses tab, I want to take the cursor/active cell right two columns, so there si an empty cell to the right of every cell.

**EDIT 2:** here is a MWE of what I have right now which should work, but which does nothing. I am adding this to the worksheet, and not as a module

```
Sub SomeActions()
    MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "SomeActions"
End Sub
```

Comment: Press Enter where? Worksheet? Userform? A little more details will help :)

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453681/can-i-capture-and-emulate-a-keydown-event-in-excel-vba) ... an old @SiddharthRout answer.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I saw that, but it is 32 bit and causes a compilation error. Simply changing the 32's to 64's does not fix the problem

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I copied it over into the workbook and module locations respectively, but it is complaining about the user32. How do I get around that?

Comment: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make an callback `Sub` that performs the logic you need. Put it into a new code module (NOT into worksheet code):

```
Sub SomeActions()
...
End Sub
```

Then, subscribe to `OnKey` event, for example, when the user opens the workbook (this code goes into `ThisWorkbook`) module in VBA editor:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "SomeActions"
End Sub
```

`"~"` means <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. For numeric keypad key use `"{ENTER}"`.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I will copy paste exactly what I have into my question.

Comment: OK some progress...when I put it in `ThisWorkbook`, it generates a run time error which reads "cannot run the macro ... the macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

Comment: Check if the Sub you subscribe to is actually the one (i.e. `SomeActions`). Also it must be in a module, not in worksheet code (see edit).

Answer (score 2):

> <sup>What I want: Everytime the user presses, and then releases, the ENTER key, for my program to do do something (ie. create a MsgBox, or call function Foo).</sup>
>  <sub>I would prefer this in the form of a MWE</sub>

If I read this correctly, you want a blank row between every user inputted value doing down and a blank column between every user inputted value going right.

On the worksheet code sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    If Target.Row / 2 <> Int(Target.Row / 2) Then r = 1
    If Target.Column / 2 <> Int(Target.Column / 2) Then c = 1
    Target.Offset(r, c).Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This occurs for all navigation. If you only want this to occur on input, modify to suit a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro instead of a [Worksheet_SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) event macro.