# Get in Excel current value in focused cell

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in, vba

I'm developing an Excel add-in.
I need to get the value from A1 cell, so I use this code

```
value = workbook.Worksheets[1].Range["A1:A1"].Value2;
```

This works great but if :
- Previous Cell value is "1"
- User types "2" but **does not press Enter or Tab**
- User activates ribbon pressing it's button

**Value2 got from this code sample is "1" (previous value) not "2" (current value shown in cell but not validated). This is wrong in my situation, I need "2".

How can I fix this?**

---

I tried forcing selection of another cell

```
 Application.ActiveCell.Offset[1, 0].Select();
```

or

```
 Application.ActiveSheet.Range["A2"].Select();
```

but no way.. "2" value is lost.

---

I also tried getting value from text area in toolbar ("2" is shown there) but don't know hoe to do!

Comment: The user is able to click on a button in your add-in in Edit Mode?

Comment: What is Edit Mode? User can click a butto in Add-in in any moment, also if he's editing a cell.

Comment: Edit Mode is similar to pressing `F2` in Excel Cell. In such a case most of the button become inactive

Comment: Is there a way to intercept Edit Mode programmatically?

Comment: Yes there is by trapping the keys. [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell) is an example

Comment: May I suggest an easy way out?

Comment: This is part of the work.. I can trap keypress but how can I trap confirm on a cell? It can be done via TAB, Enter or Mouse key..

Comment: Use `application.Interactive` to check if Excel is in Edit mode or not. `True` means the user is not in Edit mode. If it is `False` then pop a message to the user to finish editing and try again. It cannot get more simpler than this...

Comment: Ok, I'll try this.. whi don't you post an answer instead of a comment? I'll vote you

Comment: It is not about points. I was not sure you want that suggestion as an answer as it doesn't specifically answer the question :p

Comment: Interactive works.. but doesn't solve my problem: Interactive is always true, if user is editing a cell, but also if he presses Enter and focus is on another cell!

Comment: Just thought of one more alternative... When then user presses the button, simulate the `Enter` key via code and then read the value :D

Comment: I suppose is the same as Range["A2"].Select ... Recording a macro and typing Enter caused a Range Select !!

Comment: No it is not. If the cell is in edit mode then it will discard what ever is typed.

Comment: I'll do this way: if focus is on A1 I advise the user to put it out if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.Address=="$A$1") ...

Comment: Ise i can. I just tried Enter emulation: SendKeys.Send("{Enter}") but no way.. still old value in A1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46869/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-emanuele-greco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Excel in in Edit Mode (*Similar to pressing* <kbd>F2</kbd> *in an Excel's cell*), most of the buttons on the ribbon and the VBA Editor become inaccessible.

Having said that, **Can VBA code run in Edit mode**? Yes, it can as shown in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell) link

To answer your question, You will have to use API's to trap the key and then find out what the current value of the cell is. Trust me, it is not worth the pain.

**Simple Alternative**:

Use `ExcelApp.Interactive` to check for Excel's Edit mode. And if the Excel is in Edit mode then inform user to exit the cell and try again. Did a quick check on the web and found a similar example [HERE](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/03/23/excel-check-user-edit-cell/) See the section *The correct solution for all Excel versions, 2000 – 2010*

This code is in vb.net but can be easily converted to C#

```
Function IsEditing() As Boolean
    If ExcelApp.Interactive = False Then Return False
    Try
        ExcelApp.Interactive = False
        ExcelApp.Interactive = True
    Catch
        Return True
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

**C# Code from Chat**

```
bool IsEditing()
{
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive == false)
        return false;
        try
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = false;
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = true;
            }
                catch (Exception e)
            {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```