# Filter while typing in a cell

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, dynamic-typing

Would that be possible to dynamically filter rows based on a value that I type in a cell? Suppose I have a column-range with data `A10:A1000` and I filter that range on criteria I am typing in `A1` cell.

I want the filter to react dynamically, in a run time, as I am typing, not after I hit [Enter]. I found a solution for that with a text box. 
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?647621-Excel-filtering-while-typing

However, preferably, I would like to do typing in a cell not in some text box. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. With the cells, you aren't actually making any changes to the cell UNTIL you hit enter. With the textbox, though, every keystroke is a change.

Comment: You can trigger an action via change events. You have change events for left clicking, right clicking and some other stuff I guess. Gotta admit I'm slightly pessimistic towards your objective. If VBA is used to compare the cell and certain critera, I think it can be only done after pressing Enter. But I'm not sure about that

Comment: Just thought of something. You could link a cell to a textbox, then use VBA to hide/show the textbox on a selection change event. you could place the textbox right over the cell so that it looks like you're typing in the cell....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: start macro when editing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848266/excel-vba-start-macro-when-editing)

Comment: As of this demo at 03:40, it is possible https://youtu.be/mAXiZbhEfr4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution based on pivot tables. It filters hundreds of items on the file, narrowing results after typing each letter. What is more, it allows to select multiple items.

I put the item list to page filter of the pivot table. You can hide the entire rows below the page filter for aesthetics so it does not even look like a pivot table, but just a cell for type/drop-down selection of the value.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@PermaNoob has the best solution.  Excel does not allow you to check the value of a cell with VBA when you are in "edit" mode.  You could however, put a text box over `A1` and use that to run your "dynamic" search.

[Start VBA macro when editing a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848266/excel-vba-start-macro-when-editing)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 Dim searchArea As Range, searchRow As Range, searchCell As Range
 Dim searchString As String
 Dim lastRow As Integer

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 searchString = "*" & LCase(TextBox1.Value) & "*"

 ' unhide rows to have the full search field when editing
 Rows.Hidden = False

 lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Set searchArea = Me.Range("A5", "A" & lastRow) 'Me.Range("A5").End(xlDown))
 searchArea.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 For Each searchRow In searchArea.Rows
   For Each searchCell In searchRow.Cells
     If LCase(searchCell) Like searchString Then
       searchRow.Hidden = False
       Exit For
     End If
   Next searchCell
 Next searchRow

 Application.Goto Cells(1), True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the above solution and it works fine but extremely slow.

In column with 950 rows it took 13 secs to do the first letter filter.  Speed improves from 2nd letter on but for me the initial wait was unacceptable.

I ended up doing the following:

1. Created a new column (C) to filter my data in column A based on the value of cell I1
   Enter this in cell `C2: =IF(ISERR(FIND(LOWER(I$1);LOWER(A2);1));" ";"F")`
2. Created the TextBox and linked it with cell I1
3. Added the following code in VBA:

   ```
   Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
       Call Worksheet_SelectionChange(Range("I1"))
   End Sub

   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
     If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I1")) Is Nothing Then    
        Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="F"    
     End If    
   End Sub
   ```