# VBA event trigger on copy?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a method in VBA, where when in excel I copy a cell's value it triggers my function?

Or any work-arounds for that?

Or can I read key-downs and listen to Ctrl+C ?

Or can VBA read the content of copied text?

The reason is: I copy some entries from an Excel sheet to another program, and i would like to add automatically for example a gray font color to all entries which are already copied.

Comment: Answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell

Comment: If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, we'll be able to suggest a good course of action. Right now this is a fishing expedition.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? Capturing the Ctrl-C keystroke won't work if someone clicks the Copy button on the ribbon, or uses Ctrl-drag to copy the cell, or right-clicks and chooses Copy.

Comment: Would this be for something like, marking a date whenever the value has been copied?  Or perhaps writing a note or comment somewhere?  This is an interesting question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett,Tom Robinson, I copy some entries from an excel sheet to another program, and i would like to add automatically for example a gray font color to all entries which are already copied.

Comment: Please put question clarifications in the question itself, not in comments. Your question can be edited by clicking the "edit" link. Did it for you this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a shortcut key to your macro.

For example, if your macro is this:

```
Sub CopyAndMarkAsCopied()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
    With r
        .Copy
        .Font.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100) 'dark grey font
        .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200) 'light gray background
        'whatever else
    End With
End Sub
```

In Excel 2010, view macros in Developer > Macros (or keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>). In earlier versions of Excel, the menus are a bit different, but the keyboard shortcut works the same.

Select your macro in the list, and click <kbd>Options...</kbd>. In this dialog, you can assign a shortcut key to your macro. It can either be:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>some letter</kbd>, in which case you have to type a lowercase letter; or
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>some letter</kbd>; type an uppercase letter.

In this example I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (note the uppercase `C` in the screenshot below).

I probably wouldn't mask default keyboard shortcuts that I normally use, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, but you're free to do so if that's your thing.

[image]

Example in action when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a macro to <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> with an *OnKey* statement.

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Is there any way to handle the RIGHT CLICK copy method, or even a macro copying the value?  Basically, the value was READ by a process in some official way.

Comment: but would i loose the copy function?

Comment: @user2520818 You could have the macro perform **Selection.Copy** as the first order of business

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Not necessarily the "first order of business". Depending on usage, `Selection.Copy` might be the *last* line in the keydown-proc, not the first line. Ie, any operations which cancel the copy need to go *before* `Selection.Copy`. Eg, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` will cancel the copy operation, so that should go *before* `Selection.Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the OnKey statement suggestion given previously:

Application.OnKey "{UP}", "PressUp"
Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "PressDown"

"PressUp" and "PressDown" are the names of the subs that should be run. I would be hesitant about making a shortcut to run a macro that already has a pre-existing macro assigned to it. If you were to assign your macro to run when you pressed ctrl + c, it would overwrite the copy function that it already has.