# How to run a method when attempting to copy cells in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am attempting to find a way to not only prevent copying in a worksheet but replace it with a method. When someone goes to copy a cell or range, run a method that saves the whole workbook and exports the entire sheet they are on.

Context: I have a Shift Report document that takes in information for each employee's shift, when they are done, I have created a method that, when a button is pressed, will copy their specific shifts report, and generate an outlook email based on the information. Some employee's tend to either forget that button exists or choose not to use it. I want to enforce it by disabling copy and instead when attempting to copy, run that method to export it.

I have yet to find any documentation on gathering the copy/paste events, especially for specific sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> shortcut is used to copy, you can just bind your macro to that shortcut. This overwrites the default behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

1. Open "Macro" from the Developer tab (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>).
2. Click on the Sub you want to execute on copy.
3. Open "Options..."
4. Put a lowercase <kbd>c</kbd> in the Shortcut key window.
5. Press OK and exit the window.

I got the [idea from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440111/17239990).

If they use the right click menu on the other hand, it doesn't seem to be possible to prevent them from copying to something *outside* Excel itself.
([Copying *inside* Excel can be more or less disabled as seen in this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/disable-cut-copy-and-paste-in-excel-from-excel-or-any-other-non/m-p/2238431).)

If not all cells to copy are manual inputs (meaning some are determined by some formula), you could at least make it impossible to copy *all* needed data manually by disabling the "Locked" property for all manual input cells, then protecting the worksheet/-book with/-out a password, disabling the option to select locked cells.
Then, in your code, you simply add `ActiveSheet.UnProtect [password]` to the start and `ActiveSheet.Protect [password]` to the end of your sub, if it is supposed to edit some things.
This may make the "annoyance threshold" to avoid your button high enough to encourage people to use it.

Lastly, you could also make the button more prominent if possible, so users don't accidentally overlook it, and add some eye-catching reminders to the sheet.