# Autorun Excel vba code when cell value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to automatically start a certain Sub when the cell's value is Zero.

E.g. if I enter "0" into Cell A1 the following Sub is supposed to run

```
 Range("H32").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-2]C)"
```

And if I enter 1 (or any other Value above 0) into Cell A1 another Sub should run, e.g.

```
Range("B15").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C:R[-1]C)"
```

The calling of a Sub should happen right after I enter the value in excel, without pressing a button oder anything else.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried worksheet_change?

Comment: Worksheet_Change is the most you can do, but you will have to, at least, press "enter" to trigger the event. It's not possible to trigger an event when a user press a key. So it won't happen as soon as you press 0 or 1

Comment: @MaximePorté Actually, there's application.onkey as well as windows API.

Comment: @findwindow I didn't knew. Do you have a link to an implementation of it in Excel ? (I broke my laziness and google it, it was the first link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx)

Comment: I tried to use the `Application.OnKey` method and it does not appear to work while you are entering data into a cell.  I can get it to call a subroutine if I am anywhere on the spreadsheet, but not editing data, and a certain key is pressed -- but it does not appear to be called while I am entering a value into the cell.

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) will get you started

Comment: @JoshuaRoss It would a nightmare if onkey is triggered during cell edits? Consider it more like a shortcut key.

Comment: @findwindow True, but OP is only listening for 2 keys and only if you happen to be in one cell

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with this code, which I will explain below.

Open the VB Editor <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.  Right click the sheet that you want this behavior to occur on and select `View Code`.

Copy and paste the following code into the worksheet code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        'CountLarge is an Excel 2007+ property, if using Excel 2003 
        'change to just Count
        If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

        If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
                If Target.Value = 0 Then
                        Me.Range("H32").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-2]C)"
                ElseIf Target.Value = 1 Then
                        Me.Range("B15").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C:R[-1]C)"
                End If
        End If

End Sub
```

The `Worksheet_Change` event is fired every time a user makes a change to the worksheet.  If you change a cell value, for example, this event is triggered.

The first line within this subroutine checks to ensure that multiple cells weren't changed and that there was in fact an actual cell change, if either is not true then it will not continue.

Then we check to ensure that the value change happened in cell A1, if it did, we enter that `IF` statement.

From there, we check the value that was entered into cell `A1`.  If the value was 0, the appropriate formula is added to `H32`.  If the value was 1, the appropriate formula is added to `B15`.  If a value other than 0 or 1 is entered into cell A1, nothing happens.

It is important to note that you must leave the cell for this event to trigger, so while this is a good start, I don't currently know of a way to get this event to fire without at least pressing enter or leaving the cell.

### Update

After a bit of research and playing around, I've figured out how you can make this change without pressing enter or any other button, this will occur immediately after either '0' or '1' is pressed, even if you are editing the cell value.  I used a keyboard handler from [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell).

The code between the `BEGIN KEYBOARD HANDLING` and `END KEYBOARD HANDLING` event was from above.

Copy and paste the following code into the worksheet code of whichever sheet you want to capture these key strokes on:

```
Option Explicit
'BEGIN KEYBOARD HANDLING

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type MSG
    hwnd As Long
    Message As Long
    wParam As Long
    lParam As Long
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type

Private Declare Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" _
Alias "PeekMessageA" _
(ByRef lpMsg As MSG, ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, _
ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, _
ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function TranslateMessage Lib "user32" _
(ByRef lpMsg As MSG) As Long

Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" _
Alias "PostMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Long = &H100
Private Const PM_REMOVE  As Long = &H1
Private Const WM_CHAR    As Long = &H102
Private bExitLoop As Boolean

Sub StartKeyWatch()

    Dim msgMessage As MSG
    Dim bCancel As Boolean
    Dim iKeyCode As Integer
    Dim lXLhwnd As Long

    'handle the ESC key.
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
   'initialize this boolean flag.
    bExitLoop = False
    'get the app hwnd.
    lXLhwnd = FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption)
    Do
        WaitMessage
        'check for a key press and remove it from the msg queue.
        If PeekMessage _
            (msgMessage, lXLhwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN, PM_REMOVE) Then
            'strore the virtual key code for later use.
            iKeyCode = msgMessage.wParam
           'translate the virtual key code into a char msg.
            TranslateMessage msgMessage
            PeekMessage msgMessage, lXLhwnd, WM_CHAR, _
            WM_CHAR, PM_REMOVE
           'for some obscure reason, the following
          'keys are not trapped inside the event handler
            'so we handle them here.
            If iKeyCode = vbKeyBack Then SendKeys "{BS}"
            If iKeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then SendKeys "{ENTER}"
           'assume the cancel argument is False.
            bCancel = False
            'the VBA RaiseEvent statement does not seem to return ByRef arguments
            'so we call a KeyPress routine rather than a propper event handler.
            Sheet_KeyPress _
            ByVal msgMessage.wParam, ByVal iKeyCode, ByVal Selection, bCancel
            'if the key pressed is allowed post it to the application.
            If bCancel = False Then
                PostMessage _
                lXLhwnd, msgMessage.Message, msgMessage.wParam, 0
            End If
        End If
errHandler:
        'allow the processing of other msgs.
        DoEvents
    Loop Until bExitLoop

End Sub

Sub StopKeyWatch()

    'set this boolean flag to exit the above loop.
    bExitLoop = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        Me.StartKeyWatch
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
        Me.StopKeyWatch
End Sub

'End Keyboard Handling

Private Sub Sheet_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As Integer, ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

        'CountLarge is an Excel 2007+ property, if using Excel 2003 
        'change to just Count
        If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

        If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
                If KeyAscii = 48 Then
                        Me.Range("H32").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-2]C)"
                ElseIf KeyAscii = 49 Then
                        Me.Range("B15").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C:R[-1]C)"
                End If
        End If

End Sub
```

Additionally, right click on the `ThisWorkbook` object --> View Code, and add this code in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Sheets("Sheet1").StartKeyWatch
End Sub
```

Be sure to change `Sheet1` to whatever the name of your worksheet is.

The VBA will 'listen' for key presses and if the active cell is A1 and either a 0 or 1 is entered, the appropriate action will be performed even before the user does anything else.

I will add that his comes at a slight performance cost, as the code that executes on `Workbook_Open` takes a couple seconds to run.

Thanks to user [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout) for pointing out the potential issue with `Count` from Excel 2007 and on and directing me to use `CountLarge` instead.

Comment: `Target.Cells.Count` can give you error in Excel 2007+

Comment: In 2007 and later?  This code is running fine in Excel 2013 for me.

Comment: Ok do this :) Press Ctrl A so that you select all cells in the worksheet and then press Delete button. You may want to read the explanation in the duplicate post marked in the question.

Comment: Okay I will update to use `CountLarge` and assume that the user is past Excel 2003.

Comment: Wow if I knew I would be upvoted 4 times, I'd have posted an answer XD