# Map a keyboard key to an Excel button ONLY while macro is running?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with three buttons: Start clock, stop clock, and enter time. Start clock starts a clocktime display in a cell and updates at once per second. Stop clock, stops the clock. Enter time inserts into whatever cell is currently selected the current value in the clock display. Is there a way to map a single keyboard key (say insert) to the enter time button that only works if the clocktime is running, and the mapping ends once stop time is pressed?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11154285/4717755) help? I wouldn't think you want to actually map a key, but rather to capture the keystrokes and look for the one you want.

Comment: @PeterT I am not sure what you mean by capture the keystrokes. Basically a user selects a cell and then has to press the button with the mouse and id rather they could use a single key ( i can map a ctrl+key option but that is 2 keystrokes) to do so and insert seems the best choice at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a public boolean which is set to True when the clock is started and false when it is stopped, then use a key event to detect when the desired key is pressed, you can have the key do whatever it normally does when the timer is not running (boolean = false), and have it instead insert the time when the timer is running (boolean = true)

Comment: What does that look like?

Comment: @J.Doe Look at the link in PeterT's comment.  Capturing keystrokes isn't built-in in excel but its possible if you really need it

Comment: @J.Doe if you are using a form (as seems to be the case) look at the Accelerator property for form controls. This might do what you are asking