# excel 2003 vba get cell value in edit mode

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make an ajax like search in excel 2003 vba. I found a script that can catch button presses.Here -> [Is there any event that fires when keys are pressed when editing a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell)

The problem is how to get the text you are currently editing? It will be put in the Cell.Value only after you hit enter.
I was thinking you know what the cell.Value was when you started editing and you can apply the button pressies to it. This would work till you don't use the mouse to change the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to detect the key-presses, you could just build up a string of each character pressed *until* the enter key is pressed, although you might have to handle special keys like line-breaks, arrow-keys, insert, delete and backspace, and Cut/Copy/Paste.