# VBA: Is there any way to detect if DELETE key pressed?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any event to detect if DELETE key pressed on a cell in the sheet?

Here is my sample code:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Selection_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub  

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  newValue = Target.Value
  If oldValue <> newValue Then "Do Somthing"
End Sub
```

Assume A1=10, you select A1 and delete the value. So newValue=NULL and oldValue=10
Then you Instantly type "20" in the cell, So newValue=20 and oldValue should be NULL, but it is still "10".
I need to check if Delete key is pressed to update the oldValue

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  newValue = Target.Value
  If "Delete key Pressed" Then oldValue = ""
  If oldValue <> newValue Then "Do Somthing"
End Sub
```

Comment: There's the KEYPRESS event, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keypress-event

Comment: That is an event which occurs in an userform. I guess the OP talks about the user pressing the delete key in a worksheet but he is is not clear on it at all. But the answer to his question is anyway [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell).

Comment: Thanks for replies and sorry for typo in my question. so there is no build-in function to capture key-pressed event specially DELETE key?

Comment: Yes, there is also another [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) but as written above your post is not clear what your real question is.

Comment: Maybe this post will help. [Keypress Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell)

Comment: @REXXman: That is the link I alreday provided in my first comment.

Comment: I've added some description. hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, your edit does not make sense for me.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I added an example to clarify the usage.

Comment: My first advice would be to change oldValue in the change event as well.

Comment: For all practical purposes, there is no difference between pressing delete on a cell and editing the cell, removing the contents and pressing enter. You can detect either from `Worksheet_Change` by checking `IsEmpty(Target.Value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to All helps, I've found a really simple solution to my problem and it doesn't need to check if DELETE key is being pressed. Just need to update oldValue with newValue after Checking the condition.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Selection_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub  

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  newValue = Target.value
  If oldValue <> newValue Then "Do Somthing"
  oldValue = newValue ***
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Application.OnKey` to assign procedure to keys.

1. Add this code to sheet module to activate key hook:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        Application.OnKey Key:="{DEL}", Procedure:="DoSomething"
    End Sub
```

2. Add this code to sheet module to deactivate key hook:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
       Application.OnKey Key:="{DEL}"
   End Sub
```

3. Add this code to standard module:

```
    Public Sub DoSomething()
      MsgBox "Delete button pressed!"
      Selection.Clear
    End Sub
```

`Selection.Clear` command I use because OnKey overwrites the standard behavior of a key. If you don't want to delete content of cells then comment it out.