# Can Excel Worksheet Events be made to work like that of Google Translate?

Tags: excel, vba, events

I am writing a program in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to better understand the worksheet events, how it is fired and such.

My program takes the string in "*A1*" and gives the reversed string in "*B1*".

It is not as elegant as the [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.in/). In Google Translate with every keystroke, the translate function is up and running, while in my case I need to select a different cell then select "*A1*" again, for the event to fire and give the output.

Are there ways to make the events better or, create our own events, or use a combination of available events.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    If Not Intersect(Target, MyRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).value = ""
            Target.Offset(0, 1).value = ReverseWord(Target.value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Function ReverseWord(val As String)
    Dim newstring As String
    Dim pos As String
    For j = Len(val) To 1 Step -1
        pos = Mid(val, j, 1)
        newstring = newstring & pos
    Next
    ReverseWord = newstring
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: The Change event will fire when the cell value is changed, so would be better here - but note that it is not triggered with every key stroke (VBA won't run while you are editing a cell) but only once the final cell value is confirmed.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it is much better than `Worksheet_SelectionChange` . Say is there any room for further improvement ?

Comment: There is no build in OnKeystroke event in Excel. Found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell/11154285#11154285 but haven't tested it - and maybe it's a little bit to complicated if you are just playing around.

Comment: Thanks for the link @FunThomas Lemme see if whatever is in that, my cup of tea ?